# Theoretical normal distribution function in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, probability

I need to plot normal cumulative distribution for given edges of bins:

```
bin_edges = np.array([1.02,  4.98,  8.93, 12.89, 16.84, 20.79, 24.75, 28.7])
mean = 15.425
standard_deviation = 6.159900567379315
```

First I did:

```
cdf = ((1 / (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * standard_deviation)) *
   np.exp(-0.5 * (1 / standard_deviation * (bin_edges - mean))**2))
cdf = cdf.cumsum()
cdf /= cdf[-1]
```

Another way I found:

```
cdf = scipy.stats.norm.cdf(bin_edges, loc=mean, scale=standard_deviation)
```

The output of these two methods should be equal but it is not:

```
First: [0.0168047  0.07815162 0.22646339 0.46391741 0.71568769 0.89247475 
0.97468339 1.]
Second: [0.0096921  0.04493372 0.14591031 0.34010566 0.59087116 0.80832701
0.93495018 0.98444529]
```

For me it looks like scipy cdf() result is worse. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just tried creating more bins using a linear spacing `bin_edges = np.linspace(bin_edges[0], bin_edges[-1], 1000)` and found that the difference between the two curves reduces as you increase the interpolation points/bins. It looks that few number of bins (10 in your case) could be one of the reasons

Comment: You're naively calculating the numeric integral (right riemann sum?) of your distribution with too few samples. Scipy is evaluating it in closed form using the `erf` function. As @Bazingaa pointed out the two results converge if you reduce your integration step size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The problem

You're trying to calculate the CDF at every bin edge by calculating the value of the following integral at every bin edge:

[image]

The reason why your result disagrees with that of `scipy` is that `scipy` is doing the integration better than you are. You're effectively integrating the normal PDF by summing over the area of the "bars" of the histogram that your `bin_edges` effectively define. This won't produce a reasonably accurate result until your bin count is much, much higher (probably in the thousands at least). Your normalization approach is also off, since really you need to be dividing by the integral of the PDF from `-inf` to `inf`, not from `1.02` to `28.7`.

On the other hand, Numpy is just calculating a high accuracy numerical approximation of a closed form solution of the integral. The function it uses is called [`scipy.special.ndtr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ndtr.html). Here's it's [implementation in the Scipy code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/cephes/ndtr.c#L201).

## The solution

Instead of integrating by summing bar areas, you can do actual numerical integration from `-inf` to `x` in order to get a result with accuracy approaching that of `scipy.stats.norm.cdf`. Here's code for how to do that:

```
import scipy.integrate as snt

def pdf(x, mean, std):
    return ((1/((2*np.pi)**.5 * std)) * np.exp(-.5*((x - mean)/std)**2))

cdf = [snt.quad(pdf, -np.inf, x, args=(mean, std))[0] for x in bin_edges]
```

Scipy's version of `ndtr` is written in C, but here's a close Python approximation for comparison purposes:

```
import scipy.special as sps

def ndtr(x, mean, std):
    return .5 + .5*sps.erf((x - mean)/(std * 2**.5))
```

### Testing it out

```
import scipy.special as sps
import scipy.stats as sts
import scipy.integrate as snt

bin_edges = np.array([1.02,  4.98,  8.93, 12.89, 16.84, 20.79, 24.75, 28.7])
mean = 15.425
std = 6.159900567379315

with np.printoptions(linewidth=9999):
    print(np.array([snt.quad(pdf, -np.inf, x, args=(mean, std))[0] for x in bin_edges]))
    print(ndtr(bin_edges, mean, std))
    print(sts.norm.cdf(bin_edges, loc=mean, scale=std))
```

Output:

```
[0.00968036 0.04497664 0.14584988 0.34034101 0.59084202 0.80811081 0.93496465 0.98442171]
[0.00968036 0.04497664 0.14584988 0.34034101 0.59084202 0.80811081 0.93496465 0.98442171]
[0.00968036 0.04497664 0.14584988 0.34034101 0.59084202 0.80811081 0.93496465 0.98442171]
```

So when you integrate accurately, the results from the method you were using match up to high precision with those of `scipy.stats.norm.cdf`.

Comment: I used code from here: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/histogram_cumulative.html. I think the problem is that it counts distribution for histograms only. Thank you for response!

Comment: The more bins you have, the more reasonable an approximation it is to the true integral. The code you linked to uses 50 bins, as opposed to your 7. Honestly though, depending on your application, 7 bins may be enough. Keep in mind that the answer Scipy is returning is also an approximation, just a much more accurate one.

Comment: Also, notice that they're normalizing such that the peak of the (half) distributions they show are roughly at `1`. That's definitely not the correct normalization for the real CDF.

Comment: @GeorgeZorikov another thing you could check is that the _theoretical cdf_ should be exactly 1/2 at the mean value while neither yours or theirs is. On the other hand what they are calculating there is the expected _empirical CDF_ of a normal distribution sampled at the same bins. I'm not sure if that's wrong per se, but I have some doubt that's really what they wanted